# Can a JSON Schema match values from an array?

Tags: javascript, json, schema

Let's say I have the following data:

```
{
 ids: ['12345'],
 images: [{
   id: '12345',
 }]
}
```

I know that I can write a schema that can enforce that ids exist, is an array, and has a string value. I can also enforce that images have an id that is a string. But is there a way that I can enforce that the following two data blocks will fail validation using a JSON schema?

```
{
 ids: [], // should fail because the id '12345' doesn't exist, and the images array is a different length than the ids array
 images: [{
   id: '12345',
 }]
}
```

Or:

```
{
 ids: ['54321'],// should fail because 12345 doesn't match any of the ids
 images: [{
   id: '12345',
 }]
}
```